# session values in urls.py Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have 3 forms and on the basis of first form i want to display one of the two forms means i want to pass one of the two forms from urls.py
This is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^create/$',createUser),
    (r'^pay/$',payment),
    (r'^pay/mail/$',mail),
    (r'^pay/transaction/(.*)/$',transaction),
    (r'^pay/final/$',final),
    (r'^next/post/$', SomeModelFormPreview(jobpostForm)),
    (r'^post/edit/$', SomeModelFormPreview(jobpostForm)),

)
```

on the basis of fistr form post_type i want to pass the form to SomeModelFormPreview..how can i get the value of post_type in urls.py?

Answer (score 0):

Django provides [`FormWizard`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) for this exact purpose. Control sessions between a series of forms.

Comment: I don't want to use FormWizard..is there any other way?